# how to pass named optional parameter defined in dart method to ng-click attribute

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a method in dart, let's call it `showSomething()`, which has "named optional parameters"

```dart
    // the following method is in a model called ctrl.  
    void showSomething(bool _bool, {var content}){
      ....
    }
```

In dart, we can use the method like `showSomething(true, content:whatever)` or simply `showSomething(true)`.

Now in html, I have a tag
    `<div ng-click="ctrl.showSomething(true, content:something)"></div>`

Yeah, just like what you have seen, I use it the same way within dart code, but it doesn't work. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: This is probably not (yet) supported. You should make an optional parameter instead of a named optional one.

Comment: It seems like it's not supported. I guess you can file a feature request at the github project page (https://github.com/angular/angular.dart).